# Flutter runtime error with null safety assistance

Tags: flutter, dart

Have been following a tutorial made with earlier version of flutter, now with null safety, errors are bugging me though it has helped me with learning more about null safety, I am stuck. I need help.

here is the code from class model

```
class Category {
  late final int categoryId;
  late final String categoryName;
  late final String categoryDesc;
  late final int parent;
  late Image image;

  Category(
      {required this.categoryId,
      required this.categoryName,
      required this.categoryDesc,
      required this.image});

  Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    categoryId = json['id'];
    categoryName = json['name'];
    categoryDesc = json['description'];
    parent = json['parent'];
    image = (json['image'] != null ? Image.fromJson(json['image']) : null)!;
  }
}

class Image {
  late String url;

  Image({
    required this.url,
  });

  Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    url = json['src'];
  }
}
```

and the my category code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kemd/api_service.dart';
import 'package:kemd/models/category.dart' as category;
import 'package:kemd/models/category.dart' as categoryModel;

class WidgetCategories extends StatefulWidget {
  const WidgetCategories({super.key});

  @override
  State<WidgetCategories> createState() => _WidgetCategoriesState();
}

class _WidgetCategoriesState extends State<WidgetCategories> {
  late APIService apiService;

  @override
  void initState() {
    apiService = APIService();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: const [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 10),
                child: Text(
                  'All Products',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 10, right: 10),
                child: Text(
                  'View All',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Color.fromRGBO(249, 168, 37, 1)),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          _categoriesList()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _categoriesList() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: apiService.getCategories(),
      builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<List<categoryModel.Category>> model,
      ) {
        if (model.hasData) {
          return _buildCategoryList(model.data!);
        }
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(249, 168, 37, 1),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCategoryList(List<category.Category> catgories) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: catgories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var data = catgories[index];
          return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                width: 80,
                height: 80,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 15, offset: Offset(0, 5)),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Image.network(
                  data.image.url as String,
                  height: 80,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(data.categoryName.toString()),
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                    size: 14,
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

everything is without error. But having runtime error

```
Exception has occurred.
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

any help will be appreciated.

tried adding null safety to lines but unresolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after several trials changed

```
 image = json['image'] != null ? Image.fromJson(json['image']) : null;
```

to

```
image = json['image'] != null
    ? Image.fromJson(json['image'])
    : Image(url: '');
```

giving a default image link and

```
data.image.url as String,
```

to

```
data.image!.url,
```

Very much appreciated for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from

```
image = (json['image'] != null ? Image.fromJson(json['image']) : null)!;
```

because `image` isnot nullable, and forcing [null-assertion] on `) : null)!;`.

You can make dataType nullable like

```dart
Image? image
```

And assign like

```
 image = json['image'] != null ? Image.fromJson(json['image']) : null;
```

Or if you like to provide default value

```
 image = json['image'] != null ? Image.fromJson(json['image']) : Image.fromJson("defaultImage") ;
```

More about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: yes, I have added `Image? image`, but the `data.image.url` gave me error, solving it by adding null safety `!` to `data.image!.url` returns the same error as above. I am in a loop.

Comment: do a null check while reading url. Like `if(data.image!=null)...`

Comment: condition is giving me syntax error.

Comment: do `data.image != null ? YOUR_IMAGE_WIDGET : Sizedbox,shrink(),`

Comment: ok just do `child: Image.network("${data.image?.url??""}"...`  and call errorBuilder on network iamge

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, tried it, that error resolved but new error `assert(() {
                  if (widget.errorBuilder == null) {
                    // ignore: only_throw_errors, since we're just proxying the error.
                    throw error; // Ensures the error message is printed to the console.
                  }
                  return true;` guess it is not related to the former error

Comment: @RohanJariwala, SizedBox, shrink() giving syntax error. wheew!

Comment: ok just do `child:data.image`, container can take null and it is already a widget it i think